# best tool for parsing wikipeadia page and get needed informartion using php

Tags: php, mysql, web-crawler, web-scraping, domparser

I want to make one project that parse wiki pages and get needed information from it.i check some crawler and dom parser like nutch apache crawler and [simple dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).Parsing wiki page with core php is very slow.

But i cant get from

- which tools  can i  use for best optimise result?
- how to integrate [nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) like crawler with php?
- how to  store data in mysql that fetch from crawler ?
- How to organize data that fetch from crawler ?
- which level of regular expression i have to learn ?

I am new in crawler kind of project .

Thanx in advance for your priceless time.
Dont know why people closed my question.please reopen it.

Comment: This question is much to broad. Some parts of the question are probably off topic, some parts might be possible to re-post as individual questions.

Comment: What has your research turned up so far?

Comment: Question seems interesting my friend..

Comment: @Christofer i know this is broad but i write all the specification so that answerer can answer perfectly

Comment: @halfer from wikipages i  have to get title of page and some data mining type information

Comment: @sandeep - I understand that. But what code have you got so far? Or have you found any PHP libraries on search engines that might be useful? Share with us `:)`

Comment: I found simple php crawler that is out of date plus very slow..i install nutch crawler that is in java  but cant configure with php

Comment: Cool, add hyperlinks to your question?

Comment: @halfer which kind of hyperlink?

Comment: @halfer : what you know about this parsing HTML pages and scraping information ?

Comment: @sandeep - I meant add hyperlinks to your research, to reassure people that you've studied the problem thoroughly before bringing it here (which you've now done - thanks). In general, a code example is good too - if you keep problems highly specific, they won't be closed.

Comment: @halfer thanx but some people closed my question :(

Comment: For example, you could say "I've tried using SimpleXML and XMLReader to access the Media Wiki API, but it didn't let me drill down into actor information". But your question was about scraping, database design, optimisation, and regular expressions! It's too much for a single question. Break it down into parts, do the designing yourself, and ask individual how-to questions here (e.g. "I've got an HTML document scraped using file_get_contents() but it won't parse as XML. What is the best strategy/library to isolate actor name information from the text? I am using PHP 5.2 on Linux".

Comment: Yep, the question is closed. But you should now have a better idea of what research/design you need to do, and if you run into a _specific_ technical problem, ask a new question `:)`

Comment: **This is not data-mining**. I replaced the tag with the more appropriate tag [tag:web-scraping]. Data mining refers to a special type of *statistical analysis* of data, not just information extraction (otherwise it would be called [tag:information-extraction]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built in [media wiki API thats available](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) on wikipedia and there are some PHP examples on usage

> The web service API provides direct, high-level access to the data
>   contained in MediaWiki databases. Client programs can log in to a
>   wiki, get data, and post changes automatically by making HTTP requests
>   to the web service.

Comment: Ya.i install mediawiki .but its only for developing site like wikipedia but i have to get useful info from page.I dont want whole page , i want some data of page

Comment: @sandeep I dont understand sorry .. what "data"

Comment: i want data like actor and his birthdate from page

Comment: @sandeep you can get the data you need its at the top ... [see this example](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=john_Resig&rvprop=content)

Comment: Thanx @ManseUK for your effort.My Question closed by many people